# How to write data to Kinesis Data Stream with Apache Beam using Python

Tags: python, apache-beam, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to build Beam pipeline in Python that reads from and writes to AWS Kinesis Data Streams.

I am using the FlinkRunner, with Flink 1.15.4 running locally on my machine.
Python 3.8.17
Apache-beam 2.44

I use a script to publish some mock records to the source data stream:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3
import time
import re
import json
import random
import json
import csv
import pandas
import csv
from io import StringIO


client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name='af-south-1')

words = ['To be, or not to be: that is the question: ',  "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer ",'The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, ','Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, ']

counter = 0
for x in range(1):  # increase range for duplication
    
    # t_end = time.time() + 0.1 # 2 mins
    # while time.time() < t_end:
    for i in range(100):
        counter = counter + 1
        # if ride["Event ID"] == "":
        #     break
        response = client.put_record(StreamName='kds-source',
                Data=random.choice(words), PartitionKey='PartitionKey')
                
        print('Message sent #' + str(counter))
        print(response)

        # If the message was not sucssfully sent print an error message

        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200:
            print('Error')
```

Reading from the source data stream works fine and results in a list of bytes:

```
b'To be, or not to be: that is the question: '
b'Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, '
b'The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, '
b'Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, '
b'The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, '
b"Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer "
b'To be, or not to be: that is the question: '
b"Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer "
b'Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, '
b'Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, '
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to write data back to a data stream. The following:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import typing, json
from boto3 import Session

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.kinesis import ReadDataFromKinesis, InitialPositionInStream, WriteToKinesis

session = Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
current_credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

options = PipelineOptions([
    "--runner=FlinkRunner",
    "--flink_master=localhost:8081",
    "--environment_type=LOOPBACK",
    "--streaming"
])
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    output = (pipeline
    | ReadDataFromKinesis(
            stream_name="source-data-stream",
            aws_access_key=current_credentials.access_key,
            aws_secret_key=current_credentials.secret_key,
            region="af-south-1",
            max_num_records=10,
            initial_position_in_stream=InitialPositionInStream.LATEST
        )
    #| beam.Map(print) # For testing Read from Kinesis
    #| beam.Map(lambda x: [x]).with_output_types(List[bytes]) # Tried to map elements in a list
    | WriteToKinesis(
        stream_name="destination-data-stream",
        aws_access_key=current_credentials.access_key,
        aws_secret_key=current_credentials.secret_key,
        region="af-south-1",
        partition_key="partition_key")
                 )
```

results in the error:

```
ERROR:root:java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction 3: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write$KinesisWriterFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.finishBundle(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1773)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PTransformFunctionRegistry.lambda$register$0(PTransformFunctionRegistry.java:133)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:556)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:162)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:588)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:567)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:113)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write$KinesisWriterFn.flushBundle(KinesisIO.java:1038)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write$KinesisWriterFn.finishBundle(KinesisIO.java:1018)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.onPutRecordResult(KinesisProducer.java:197)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.access$000(KinesisProducer.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler$1.run(KinesisProducer.java:138)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 20
     13 options = PipelineOptions([
     14     "--runner=FlinkRunner",
     15     "--flink_master=localhost:8081",
     16     "--environment_type=LOOPBACK",
     17     "--streaming"
     18 ])
     19 with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
---> 20     output = (pipeline
     21     | ReadDataFromKinesis(
     22             stream_name="source-data-stream", 
     23             aws_access_key=current_credentials.access_key,
     24             aws_secret_key=current_credentials.secret_key,
     25             region="af-south-1",
     26             max_num_records=10,
     27             initial_position_in_stream=InitialPositionInStream.LATEST
     28         )
     29     | WriteToKinesis(
     30         stream_name="destination-data-stream", #output stream
     31         aws_access_key=current_credentials.access_key,
     32         aws_secret_key=current_credentials.secret_key,
     33         region="af-south-1",
     34         partition_key="partition_key")
     35                  )

File ~/umoja/beam-poc-dev/beam-3_8-2_44/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py:601, in Pipeline.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
    599   if not exc_type:
    600     self.result = self.run()
--> 601     self.result.wait_until_finish()
    602 finally:
    603   self._extra_context.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

File ~/umoja/beam-poc-dev/beam-3_8-2_44/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py:607, in PipelineResult.wait_until_finish(self, duration)
    604   self._observe_state(message_thread)
    606 if self._runtime_exception:
--> 607   raise self._runtime_exception
    609 return self._state

RuntimeError: Pipeline BeamApp-charlverster-0911183110-7887ddee_787e8261-dded-4db2-baf6-f880015b2da7 failed in state FAILED: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction 3: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write$KinesisWriterFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.finishBundle(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1773)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PTransformFunctionRegistry.lambda$register$0(PTransformFunctionRegistry.java:133)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:556)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:162)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:588)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:567)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:113)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write$KinesisWriterFn.flushBundle(KinesisIO.java:1038)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write$KinesisWriterFn.finishBundle(KinesisIO.java:1018)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.onPutRecordResult(KinesisProducer.java:197)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.access$000(KinesisProducer.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler$1.run(KinesisProducer.java:138)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

From the documentation WriteToKinesis is 'An external PTransform which writes byte array stream to Amazon Kinesis'. I've tried mapping the data as a list with:

`| beam.Map(lambda x: [x]).with_output_types(List[bytes])`

but that also doesn't seem to work.

How do I write to a Kinesis data stream?

EDIT: I was an idiot. I had the name of the destination data stream wrong in my code.